# Motion tracking no longer working on 6S

Tags: iphone, motion-processor

I recently purchased an iPhone 6S, and the motion tracking worked for a few days, but then in the past four days it has recorded no steps or flights climbed. This morning, the phone started recording data again, but only briefly (maybe 2 hours); it currently is not collecting any motion data. I've been using Apple's Health app and the FitBit app. I tried turning motion tracking off and then back on, restarted the phone, no luck. I'm on iOS 9.0.2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your iPhone by holding the lock button and home button together until you see an Apple logo appear. If that doesn't work, I'd attribute that issue to a bug. The iPhone 6S is kind of buggy, mine won't play system or Taptic Feedback sounds sometimes. So we may just have to wait for software updates.